# How many combinations of magic square on a white Rubik's cube?

Tags: co.combinatorics

A magic square is one in which the sum of the numbers in each row, column, and both main diagonals is the same. The numbers in the magic square can only be 1 to 9.

a 3x3 magic square example:
[image: a 3x3 magic square example]

There are 8 combinations of a 3x3 magic square.

A white Rubik's cube has 6 sides. There are 9 spaces on each side for numbers from 1 to 9, without color.
[image: a white Rubik's cube]

If we fill each side of a white Rubik's cube with a magic square, how many combinations can be filled on this Rubik's Cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that each magic square must be composed of numbers $1,2,\dots,9$ (or $1,2,\dots, n^2$ in general), and that under filling a cube with magic squares we understand assigning a number to each $1\times 1\times 1$ cell at the cube surface such that the numbers at each face form a magic square.

Filling $3\times 3\times 3$ cube with magic squares is not possible. Notice that the center number of a magic square is $5$, and once a number at a corner of a magic square is fixed to be $a\ne 5$, the number at the opposite corner (ie. on the same diagonal as $a$) is $10-a\ne a$. However, in the cube with corners having coordinates $\pm 1$ (say), there is a triangle with vertices $(-1,-1,-1)$, $(-1,1,1)$, $(1,-1,1)$, whose sides are formed by surface (magic) diagonals, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have clarified my question.

Comment: @ChuckLiu: I don't see much clarification with respect to cube filling. Does my interpretation match your intended question for $n=3$?

Comment: I assume the six sides (up, down), (left, right), (forward, backward).
For (up, down), we can get 8 combinations. So I think the number of combination is between from $8$ to $8^3$.

Comment: @ChuckLiu: Then magic squares become irrelevant. Think of them as colors and thus one need to enumerate independent colorings of the cube faces. Solution to this problem is well known, even if we count colorings up to rotations of the cube.